# What Can I Do To Make Visul Studio 2022 17.3.4 ndroidd Emulator Work?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I try to create my first xamrin app. Unfortunetly my aadnroid emulator doesn't work. When I Press run program button in Visual Studio, emulator is popping up and closing after a second.
**Here is my build output:**  [image: Here is my build output]

**Here is how my sdk looks like:**
[image: Here is my build output:]

[image: Here is my build output:]

**And there is what i installed in Visual Studio Installer:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Put a break point at end of code in VS or add at end Console.ReadLine() so you can see the error message before closing.  You can also step through code using F11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do the following:

- Check whether the Windows Hypervisor Platform is enabled. Open Windows Features tool, click on the Turn Windows features on and verify if Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform are enabled.
- Change the Xamarin Diagnostics output verbosity to Diagnostics. After that attach the build output.
- On Visual Studio open the Android Command prompt (Tools\Android\Android Adb Command Prompt), run the following command below and attach the output:
- Check the virtualization acceleration `{android-sdk-path}\emulator\emulator.EXE -accel-check`
- Try to launch the emulator: `{android-sdk-path}\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -verbose -avd {avd name} -prop monodroid.avdname={avd name}`
- You will find the {android-sdk-path} in Options > Xamarin > Android Settings

Comment: Actually first bullet point did the work, thanks for help :)